# how to change font of info bar in lightbox of photo gallery plugin wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am using Photo gallery plugin in my website. link : http://mycompany.co.nf/2/fashion/
On this page clicking on any photo leads to lightbox gallery view. In that clicking on I shows photo name or info at right top corner. I want to change that font to special elite Google font. But can't figure out which file to modify. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
html body #catablog-lightbox-meta .catablog-lightbox-title {
font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 10pt;
line-height: 1;
}
```

Comment: Hi Ahmed, I searched thorough view source code, I want to change properties of Div bwg_image_title, it is inside div spider_popup_wrap. when I unchecked font-family: segoe ui; from properties, I am getting desired result as the font that I have used in my theme css file, i.e special elite google font, which is in logo and title of the page in website. but I don't know where to change the code. Please   first open the view source and then open gallery lightbox. In source  , there is div bwg._image_title inside div spider_popup_wrap. I need to change its property.

Comment: Please let me know how to change this property in css